# \makefirstuc from glossaries clashes with \foreignlanguage from babel

Tags: glossaries, babel

I write a document, whose primary language is English. But I have some glossary entries whose names (aka label) are in German, but the description, etc. is in English again. I use the packages `glossaries` and `babel`.

So, some of my glossary definitions look like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
    name={\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{Foo}},%
    description={(ger.) German word for Bar.}%
}
```

Additionally, I want every entry in the glossary to start with a capital letter. Hence, I redefined

```
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\makefirstuc{#1}}
```

in the preamble. This results into a compilation error.

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \languagename
```

Instead, if I protected the argument with an addition `{}`, i.e.

```
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\makefirstuc{{#1}}}
```

the compilation is successful, but then the whole entry is capitalized not only the first letter. But that's not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to define a new command to switch the language

```
\newcommand*{\ngerman}[1]{\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{#1}}
```

and then define the glossary entry as

```
\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
    name={\ngerman{Foo}},%
    description={(ger.) German word for Bar.}%
}
```

instead. This way, the first argument of `\foreignlanguage` is hidden from `\makefirstuc`. Of course, a more general solution that could deal with arbitrary bi-parametric macros would be nice, but it is OK, because German is the only second languange that I need in my document.